# JBOSS 7.2.2 External Folder Linking

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have been searching around for this specific problem of mine. We have a folder that is on a shared folder on another server "\\server1\shares\web\images" and I want to link this folder into my web application in Jboss 7.2.2. I'm migrating from Jboss 4.2.2 to Jboss 7.2.2.

Here is my `server.xml` file from Jboss 4.2.2. You'll notice that the `<Context>` tag handles this link for me.

```
<Server>
<Service name="jboss.web">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">
        <!-- ... -->
        <Host name="myApp" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"
            deployXML="false" configClass="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.config.JBossContextConfig">
            <!-- ... -->
            <Context path="/images" appBase="" docBase="\\server1\shares\web\images"
                debug="99" reloadable="true" />
            <!-- ... -->
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

My research has lead me to use modules, but I cannot figure out how to use the modules properly for this problem. Most examples shows how to provide some link to a folder on the same machine as the Jboss server is on.

So, am I suppose to use modules or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: First I would move to WildFly since JBoss AS 7 is old and not maintained anymore and configure my application there (http://docs.wildfly.org/15/Admin_Guide.html#Undertow for the web part)